# Cryptoanalysis - Transposition cipher

Tags: encryption

I am struggling with this message. Can someone break it?

TSRBROMEJYESKONLLUAKEDODBYYCTBIYLUYSODLBYKTSCNSAIIDLYNPENIOMTOAPSJMSYOEAULTNNEUOAEKJRKEMUODDKOYPNINRATDYINTEXXEOXSPEAXXLJXXXXS

It is probably transposition cipher and it can be in English, German, Slovak or Czech language. According to index of coincidence, it is probably Czech.

Thanks for any help

Comment: What language typically has 4 letters in a row (`XXXX`)?  Maybe this is not a word, a code or suchlike.  Have you tried frequency analysis?

Comment: I think those X letters are here just to fill gaps, so the length of the text was divisible by length of the key permutation. I have tried frequency analysis and the numbers were different from statisctics. But I think it's because this message is too short.

Comment: "Please decrypt this blob of data" is rarely a programming question and also usually too broad. The help section contains useful tips on what questions are on-topic here and what makes a good question. You should read it.